# DNS VIEW not working for any

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

I have configured a DNS view configuration:

```
view  "local-lan" {
  match-clients { 192.168.0.0/24 };
  zone "localtesting.com" { 
    type master;
    file "internal/internal.localtesting.com";
  };
};

view "any" {
  match-clients { any }; 
  zone "betatesting.com" {
    type master;
    file "external/betatesting.com";
  };
};
```

When I tried to access betatesting.com domain from 192.168.0.0/24 network server, it matches with only `local-lan` view and returned `NXDOMAIN`. I want it to match `any` if the zone is not present in `local-lan`. Anybody please give me some details on it.

Comment: "I hope it suppossed to match any if the zone is not present in local-lan" That is now how it works. First the client is matched from its source to see which views should be applied and then the content of the view is given as answer. You may wish to take a step back and explain more in details what you want to achieve and why you implemented it with bind views, as it may or may not be the easiest way to achieve your goals.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. 192.168.0.0/24 network servers alone need to use the zone localtesting.com rest of the network should be able to access betatesting.com zone including 192.168.0.0/24 network.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.0.0/24 network servers alone need to use the zone localtesting.com rest of the network should be able to access betatesting.com zone including 192.168.0.0/24 network.

Anybody have any idea on this ??